# intent.putExtra doesn´t deliver newest values of a string to intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-alarms

I use `AlarmManager` and try to give some values in `putExtra` to my `BroadcastReceiver`. The values I send go to the `BroadcastReceiver`, **it works fine to transmit values**.

But I send my variable "counter" and I always get the old values that existed on the first start of my `setRepeating()`. And I know that the counter values are ways more high that I see there. So when the values change nothing happens. ***How can I have an event every half hour with right values?!***

I've searched now for 3 hours but can't find a  solution to make an interaction of my `AlarmManager` and some values out of a Sensor...

```
public void startAlarm(View view) {

    try {
        AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                MyAlarmReceiver.class);

         intent.putExtra("startStepCounter", startStepCounter);
         intent.putExtra("lastStepCounter", lastStepCounter);

        final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,
                1234567, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        alarms.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                System.currentTimeMillis(), timeToAlarmMilli, pIntent);

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}

public class MyAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.i("Alarm Receiver", "Entered");


      //
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    int local_start = bundle.getInt("startStepCounter");
    int local_last = bundle.getInt("lastStepCounter");

    Toast.makeText(context,
            "ALARM  " + local_start + " " + local_last,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
}
```

Comment: Please provide code :D

Comment: code is now in the text

Comment: Where are you updating your counter?

Comment: where is your counter? and any increment statement?

Answer (score 0):

look at this part of your code

```
  final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,
                1234567, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

you need to provide uniuque id for secound part each time you use pending intent, so instead of 1234567, use a unique id.